# Explode a row into multiple rows based on a column value presto

Tags: sql, presto

I am looking to explode a row into multiple rows based on a column[integer] value, I am trying to do this using presto

Below is an example

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |

expected output

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

in the above example, id 1 has to be repeated 5 times and id 2 has to be repeated 2 times based on the count.
Based on my experience, presto doesnt support recursive CTE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursive CTE's here, you can use [`sequence`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) or [`repeat`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#repeat) to generate an array for corresponding length and then flatten it with [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, count) AS (
   VALUES (1, 5),
    (2, 2)
)

-- query
select id, count
from dataset,
unnest (repeat(id, count)) as t (ignore)
-- unnest (sequence(0, count - 1)) as t (ignore)
```

Output:

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

Comment: Thanks! Let me try and update you

Answer (score 0):

You could make the count into array with `REPEAT` and then `CROSS JOIN`.

Your input:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
SELECT id, count
FROM (
  VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (2, 2)
) AS x (id, count)
```

Then:

```
SELECT id, t.count
FROM test
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(repeat(count, count)) AS t (count)
```

Comment: you can actually skip `cross join` here substituting it by comma (which will be expanded into cross join).